# positioning popups on partial views

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a partial view that I would like to incorporate my popup/notifications into. I would like to position these notifications around the two "buttons". However, I'm not actually sure how to position these popups around the buttons. In the documentation examples, it states to use the id of the popup div in the href of where the popup should occur.

example:

```
<a href="#popupPadded" data-rel="popup" data-role="button">Popup with padding</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupPadded" class="ui-content">
  <p>This is a popup with the <code>ui-content</code> class added to the popup container.</p>
</div>
```

***But my partial view is being used somewhere else with href="#". How can I position my popups in the partial view and also reuse them on other pages?***

Here is the HTML for my partial view:

```
<a href="#" data-icon="GhCsStatus-Red"  data-position-to="origin"    data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" id="GhCsStatus_CS" style="pointer-events: none;">CS</a>    
<a href="#" data-icon="GhCsStatus-Red"  data-position-to="origin"    data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" id="GhCsStatus_GH" style="pointer-events: none;">GH</a>

<div id="GH_popup" data-role="popup">
<p> Get History is OFF! </p>
</div>

<div id="CS_popup" data-role="popup">
<p> Communication Service is OFF! </p>
</div>      

<div id="GHCS_popup" data-role="popup">
<p> Get History and Communication Service are OFF! </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What you can do is first get the button x and y values (position) and open the popup `$('#id').popup('open', { x: value, y: value});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

`.offset()` will give the desired results unlike `.position()`.

---

First you need to get the button's position using either [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) or <strike>[`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/)</strike> which is related to the popup you want to open.

> **[Demo - .offset()](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/BTBJG/)** updated
>
> <strike>**Demo - .position()**</strike>

```
var x_pos = $("#btn_id").offset().left;
var y_pos = $("#btn_id").offset().top;
```

And then open the popup

```
$('#popup_id').popup('open', { x: x_pos, y: y_pos });
```

**Note**: You can open only one popup at a time.

Comment: @Liondancer I've added demo.

Comment: my buttons are located on the bottom right footer using jQuery mobile. I was wondering if I could implement their positioning attritbutes. http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/

Comment: @Liondancer positioning the buttons or the popups?

Comment: You got the right idea but I'm having trouble understanding this code since I'm new to CSS =/

Comment: @Liondancer what problem are you facing?

Comment: sorry I'm not at my work computer right now so I dont have the files in front of me to look at =/ But I'm just a bit confused

Comment: @Liondancer dont worry, anything can be fixed :)