# How to position a jQuery Mobile popup with some horizontal shift from the origin?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I'm using a JQM popup as a horizontal sub-menu, like in the image below. By clicking the first vertical button, the sub-menu will open.

[image]

The size of the menu buttons is not fixed but is set as a percentage, as this buttons are, let say, adaptive to the viewport height (like in the JQM Demo for responsive Listviews):

```
.menu .ui-listview li > .ui-btn {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* include padding and border in height so we can set it to 100% */
    border-color: rgb(102,102,102);
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 32px;
    padding: 0; /* To make it small. */
}
```

Now, i have some trouble to position the popup with some left margin to the right side of my main vertical menu, because as default, the popup will overlap with the origin.

**EDIT:**
This is a Javascript possible implementation:

```
$("#left-sub-menu").on({
    popupbeforeposition: function(e, ui) {
        var px = $("#left-menu").outerWidth()           // left margin
                 + $(this).parent().outerWidth() / 2    // center of popup container
                 + 10;  // if left arrow, add default half arrow width  
        ui.x = px;
    }
});
```

but i'm askng if there is a CSS solution using the markup data-position.

I tried also with a hidden div with width=200% near the vertical button that should act as a "fake origin", here is the example:

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/qmGhNqgww2mkKX1QywLH?p=preview

but, the position of the popup is relative to its center, so i would need always to know the number of items inside the sub menu.

Someone knows if  is possible to position a JQM popup with a certain offset in percentage from the origin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19061530/1771795

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515403/how-do-i-update-the-position-of-a-jquery-mobile-global-popup/20517755#20517755

Comment: you are absolutely sure, there is no way with a css right-positioned anchor and data-position-to markup? BTW, i'm a great fan of you...:-)

Comment: Since button's dimensions aren't fixed, you have to do it dynamically by calculating both `offset().top` and `.outerWidth()` to update popup's `x` position. Thanks for the kind compliment :)

Comment: Something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/FHgyyfUFB3ZY1csoYEr9?p=preview but still not 100% working. Could be a bug or an issue in your custom css. Will check it tomorrow.

Comment: it looks like a bug, it ignores overridden values of x & y. Check console log https://plnkr.co/edit/QVJI1Qepj9FK5yQrSxcc?p=preview